# Submit button and Client script button conflicting on Suitelet. SS 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

i have 2 buttons on my suitelet form, Standard Submit Button and Client Script button. The submit button does not execute if i have the `clientScriptModulePath` in my suitelet code. once i remove the `clientScriptModulePath` , the submit button starts working. Anyone have any idea what could be the reason?

Suitelet:

```
 function onRequest(context) {
  log.debug('request type', context.request.method);
  var form = serverWidget.createForm({ title: 'Item Search' });
  if (context.request.method === 'GET') {
    var rec_id = context.request.parameters.id;
    log.debug('rec id', rec_id)

    form.addButton({
      id: 'custpage_btn_goback',
      label: 'Go Back',
      functionName: 'onBackButtonClick'
    });
    form.clientScriptModulePath = '../client/mx_itemsearch_filter_cs.js';

    form.addSubmitButton({
      label: 'Submit'
    });
    context.response.writePage(form);
  }
  else {
    log.debug('POST', 'POST')
  }
}
```

Client script function:

```
function onBackButtonClick() {//TODO:
  try {
    console.log('in back button')

    var currRec = currentRecord.get();

    var suiteletUrl = url.resolveScript({
      scriptId: 'customscript_mx_itemsearch_sl',
      deploymentId: 'customdeploy_mx_itemsearch_sl'
    });
    console.log(suiteletUrl)

    window.open(suiteletUrl, '_self');

  } catch (e) {
    log.error({ title: fx, details: 'Error - Code: ' + e.code + ', Message: ' + e.message });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one valid client side endpoint function. The endpoint function can just be a blank function.  Example

```
function pageInit (context) {};
```

The your client script should have export the client endpoint function and your custom function.

```
return { pageInit: pageInit, onBackButtonClick: onBackButtonClick};
```